# MyBatis просит неверный тип

Tags: postgresql, spring, mybatis

Класс, содержащий в качестве полей объекты других классов:

```
public class ReservedRoom {

private int id;

private float price;

private boolean isPaid;

private Date startDate;

private Date endDate;

private User user;

private Room room;
/* getters and setters */
```

ResultMap и select запрос

```
<resultMap id="ReservedRoomResultMap" type="com.example.hotelreservationapi.domains.ReservedRoom">
    <id property="id" column="id"/>
    <result property="price" column="price"/>
    <result property="startDate" column="start_date"/>
    <result property="endDate" column="end_date"/>
    <result property="isPaid" column="is_paid"/>
    <association property="user" column="user_id" javaType="com.example.hotelreservationapi.domains.User">
        <id property="id" column="uId"/>
        <result property="login" column="login"/>
        <result property="password" column="password"/>
        <result property="name" column="name"/>
        <result property="surname" column="surname"/>
        <result property="middlename" column="middlename"/>
        <result property="email" column="email"/>
    </association>
    <association property="room" column="room_id" javaType="com.example.hotelreservationapi.domains.Room">
        <id property="id" column="rId"/>
        <result property="number" column="number"/>
        <result property="numberOfRooms" column="number_of_rooms"/>
        <result property="roomClass" column="class"/>
        <result property="surname" column="surname"/>
        <result property="pricePerDay" column="price_per_day"/>
        <result property="isFree" column="is_free"/>
    </association>
</resultMap>

<select id="read" resultMap="ReservedRoomResultMap">
    select reserved_rooms.id,
           reserved_rooms.price,
           reserved_rooms.start_date,
           reserved_rooms.end_date,
           reserved_rooms.is_paid,
           users.id as uId,
           users.login,
           users.password,
           users.name,
           users.surname,
           users.middlename,
           users.email,
           rooms.id as rId,
           rooms.number,
           rooms.number_of_rooms,
           rooms.class,
           rooms.price_per_day,
           rooms.is_free
    from reserved_rooms
             left JOIN users on reserved_rooms.user_id = users.id
            left join rooms on reserved_rooms.room_id = rooms.id
</select>
```

Поля таблицы:
id - serial

user_id - integer

room_id - integer

price - real

is_paid - boolean

start_date - date

end_date - date

При выполнение запроса выдаёт ошибку

```
2021-10-26 09:12:10.549 ERROR 1208 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Error attempting to get column 'start_date' from result set.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type int : 2021-10-25
```

; Bad value for type int : 2021-10-25; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type int : 2021-10-25] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type int : 2021-10-25

**Почему Postgre пытается привести третью колонку к типу int?** Пробовал менять колонки местами, ставил is_paid на третье место, тоже пытался привести к int

*При выполнение запроса в PGadmin возвращает верные данные и без ошибок*

Comment: Это не postges пробует привести к int. Это по какой-то причине, mybatis пробует достать эту колонку как `int`, а постгрес справедливо отвечает, что на знает, как превратить дату в `int`. Какой точный тип поля `startDate`, т.е. из какого пакета `Date`? C `java.util.Date` никогда не возникало проблем. Еще вопрос, у вас геттеры и сеттеры для полей с датой, самые обычные, т.е. возвращают значение поля без преобразований?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Починил методом тыка. **Удалил конструктор из класса Room** и всё заработало как нужно. Странно, в классе User конструктор есть и ничем не мешает.